# Login box to right of header

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling to have my login box to the right of my header near the top right of the page.  I would like the header and everything in blue to be next to each other with the login box in the top right still in the blue, with the rest of the page in white. Through my CSS using the .left and .right div tags I was not able to accomplish that.

```css
* {
  color: #000000;
}

body {
  margin: 0px 150px 0px 150px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

div.header {
  background-color: #b3d9ff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
}

div.page {
  color: #e6f2ff;
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 2200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="header">
    <div id="left">
      <h1>Welcome to the best blog in the world!</h1>
      <h6>I know you're jealous...</h6>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>
          <h4>Already a member? Login here:</h4>
        </legend>

        <form method="GET" action="http://csis.svsu.edu/~cmdewey/thankyou.html">
          Login name:
          <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname"><br><br> Password:
          <input type="password" id="secretpass" name="secretpass"><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored the html snd css because you were using class selectors in html instead of id selectors.

```css
* {
  color: #000000;
}
body {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #b3d9ff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
}
div.page {
  color: #e6f2ff;
}
img {
  padding: 10px;
}
.left {
  width: 50%; 
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
<div class="header">
<div class="left">
 <h1>Welcome to the best blog in the world!</h1>
 <h6>I know you're jealous...</h6></div>

<div class="right">
<fieldset><legend>
<h4>Already a member? Login here:</h4></legend>

<form method="GET" action="http://csis.svsu.edu/~cmdewey/thankyou.html">
  Login name:
<input type="text" id="uname" name="uname"><br><br>
  Password: 
<input type="password" id="secretpass" name="secretpass"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form></fieldset></div></div>

enter image description here
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your header class : `display:inline-flex`

so change it like this :

```
div.header {
   background-color: #b3d9ff;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
   display:inline-flex;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/rpqzvgwq/1/

Comment: Thanks that worked, now how do I get it to align to the top right ? This places it next to the title leaving the second half of the header open space.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is Well,Just you have a few wrong :

> 1)you use `ID` in tag html but use `.` selector in css.
>
> 2)you dont need to `margin-left: 2200px;` in `#right`.
>
> 3)use `overflow: auto;` in `.header`.
>
> 4)use `box-sizing: border-box;` in `#left` and `#right`.

I Fix them ,I hope help you,

**Full Code:**

```css
* {
  color: #000000;
}

body {
  color: #ffffff;
}

div.header {
  background-color: #b3d9ff;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#page {
  color: #e6f2ff;

}

img {
  padding: 10px;
}

#left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#right{
width: 50%;
float: right;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
<div class="header">
<div id="left">
    <h1>Welcome to the best blog in the world!</h1>
     <h6>I know you're jealous...</h6>
</div>
<div id="right">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <h4>Already a member? Login here:</h4>
                </legend>
                <form method="GET" action="http://csis.svsu.edu/~cmdewey/thankyou.html">
                  Login name:
                <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname"><br><br>
                  Password: 
                <input type="password" id="secretpass" name="secretpass"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```